# working in React js with firebase : TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my code:

```
  48 | let allevents = [];
  49 | 
  50 | 
> 51 | database.child("myevents").child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on("value", function(snapshot){
         ^  
  52 | 
  53 |     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  54 |         var obj = childSnapshot.val();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null using website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554970/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-uid-of-null-using-website)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing.

So in your case you need to check if `user` is present in `onAuthStateChanged` callback:

```
let allevents = [];

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.child("myevents").child(user.uid).on("value", ...)
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```